# Python: Anyway to use map to get first element of a tuple

Tags: python, map-function

I have a tuple of tuples and I want to put the first value in each of the tuples into a set. I thought using map() would be a good way of doing this the only thing is I can't find an easy way to access the first element in the tuple. So for example I have the tuple `((1,), (3,))`. I'd like to do something like `set(map([0], ((1,), (3,))))` (where `[0]` is accessing the zeroth element) to get a set with 1 and 3 in it. The only way I can figure to do it is to define a function: `def first(t): return t[0]`. Is there anyway of doing this in one line without having to declare the function?

Comment: You could use a lambda, if you fancy map more than a list comprehension, `lambda x: x[0]`.

Comment: If you don't want lambda, you can use itemgetter(0) along with map.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Use a list comprehension:

```
data = ((1,), (3,))
print([x[0] for x in data])
```

Comment: Using the itemgetter (per Steve Howard's answer) is arguably the better as it was designed specifically for this purpose.

Comment: @AaronTorgerson, I don't agree. I think this is more readable as it uses python syntax to express it rather then a special object.

Comment: Context matters. If I want to sort by a tuple element, using `itemgetter` beats writing a lambda

Answer (score 19):

Use [`operator.itemgetter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter):

```
from operator import itemgetter
map(itemgetter(0), ((1,), (3,)))
```

While the list comprehensions are generally more readable, `itemgetter` is closest to what you asked for. It's also a bit faster:

```
>>> from timeit import timeit
>>> setup = 'from operator import itemgetter; lst=( ("a",), ("b",), (1,), (2,))'
>>> timeit('map(itemgetter(0), lst)', setup=setup)
0.13061050399846863
>>> timeit('[i[0] for i in lst]', setup=setup)
0.20302422800159547
```

Comment: The two techniques cannot be compared in terms of speed as they serve different purposes. `map` creates a generator, whereas list comprehension creates a list. A fairer comparison would be between list comprehension and `list(map(itemgetter(0), lst))`, which produce similar timing results. But generators are usually preferred if possible.

Answer (score 4):

```
my_set = {x[0] for x in TUPLES}
```

Answer (score 3):

Python supports the creation of anonymous function using the [`lambda`](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/controlflow.html#lambda-forms) keyword. This allows you to use a function without formally defining it. Given your example, you'd use the lambda like this:

```
data = ((1,), (3,))
set(map(lambda x: x[0], data))
```

This is equivalent to:

```
def f(x):
    return x[0]

set(map(f, data))
```

But as other people have said, list comprehensions are preferred over the use of map.

Comment: I totally copy pasted from @Winston

Comment: If I could have stolen the whole answer, I would have!

Answer (score 3):

Just another way to get it:

```
set(x for x, in data)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a set comprehension in Python 2.7 and 3.x:

```
>>> t = ((1,), (3,))
>>> s = {x[0] for x in t}
>>> s
set([1, 3])
```

or in Python < 2.7:

```
>>> s = set([x[0] for x in t])
>>> s
set([1, 3])
```

Answer (score 2):

```
data = ((1,), (3,))
s = set(zip(*data)[0])
```

If there are more items in your tuples you might save some memory and time using izip and islice.

Answer (score 1):

Go with @Winston. List comprehensions are great. If you *really* want to use map, use a lambda as previously suggested, or the logically equivalent...

```
from operator import itemgetter
data = ((1,), (3,))
map(itemgetter(0), data)
```

This is just for info; You should use the list comp